# How to use a batch file to check WinService Status?

Tags: windows, batch-file, service

I created a WinService and set up its start and stop on Scheduled Tasks. But everyday after the service is started for about 20 seconds, it automatically stops without any alert even though in Scheduled Task I did setup re-starting if starting fails. Therefore, I have to re-start the service manually everyday morning. Now, I want to write a batch file that can implement the following tasks:

1. Check where the WinService is running
2. If not in 1), start the service
3. Write the record for 1) and 2).

Appreciate if you can provide a walk-through procedure for it.

Comment: is winservise the name of your service?

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

set "sevice_name=WinService"

sc query "%sevice_name%" | find /i "running" || (
    echo service "%sevice_name%" is stopped
    sc start "%sevice_name%"
    goto :end

) >> log.txt

:end
echo service "%sevice_name%" is running >> log.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Could you verify the procedure (w/ questions) likes that below:  1) Create a .batch file w/ the content as you recommended, in which service_name=myWinServiceName; 2) for log.txt - Can it look like: C;\MyTemp\log.txt; 3) How to run the .bat? - Put it in Scheduled Task?  Thanks again

Comment: @ShaningYu - you can specify any location for the log file.If it is longer you can enclose it with quotes.You can also add one additional "echo %date%>>log.txt" for more clearenace. You scehdule the bat , but better run it twice with turned on and turned off service for checkeing.If you schedule the bat you can also add a time out to be sure that the service is turned down already (if it is doing so).

Comment: Thanks.  Will try and see the result.

Comment: Thanks to npocmaka - Using his approach, the stopped service got re-started after checking the status.

Comment: @ShaningYu - if everything is ok you can accept the answer which will give both of us some points :-)